# Context is lost after Navigator.push

Tags: flutter, provider, navigator

```
Provider.of<IsSpecialist>(context).value
```

is accessible above this Navigator.push:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => ChatScreen()));
```

But in after the Navigator.push it's unavailable in ChatScreen:

```
Provider.of<IsSpecialist>(context).value
```

returns

```
Could not find the correct Provider above this Widget
```

Why is context broken? How to maintain the original context? 
My current temporary solution is to get isSpecialist from Provider before the Navigator and send it as a parameter to the ChatScreen, but I need to find a better solution.

Comment: Did you make sure you provided `IsSpecialist` above both?

Comment: can you post the code here?

Answer (score 3):

Provider should be placed on the top of the widget tree, above MaterialApp

Comment: I had the same problem. Putting the provider before the Material App did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Context is not getting lost, you are just using the wrong context.
suppose `A -> B -> C` is the widget hierarchy.

I think you are pushing your `IsSpecialist` at `B` and accessing it in `C` but you are using context of `A`.

It would be more clear if you can post some more code that can give idea about your widget hierarchy.

Comment: I've fixed my widget hierarachy by wrapping materialapp into multiprovider, and now the provider values are available across the whole app. Thanks!

Comment: If it helped you then please up-vote and accept the answer so that I can get some credit.

Answer (score 0):

While yo could simply things stating that `MultiProvider()` should be above the `MaterialApp()`, in fact it has to be above the `AppRouter()` instantiation so AppRouter's context will have access to the Provider you need.

I agree that for practical reasons it's kind of the same but for educational purposes, it's better to be more accurate.